# Redo Category Page - Remove images and have attribute grid

Tags: product, attributes, category

I'm using Magento to sell tickets to events and have a Category for each different event.

I'm using a Grouped product for the Specific date and then simple products in the group for the individual ticket categories.

I'd like to redo the category page on magento to remove images for individual grouped items as i only need on header image per event.

Would it be possible to create a category page similar to this

http://www.stubhub.com/new-york-rangers-tickets/?osid=homepage__module_trending-now_top

Where the date is an attribute, the event is the grouped product name, the location and time is an attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can do whatever you want with every page

## Remove the image per product

The product grid is defined here:

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

If you change this template, copy it to your personal theme

```
/app/design/frontend/mypackage/<mytheme I recommend default>/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

then change it. Just search for the `<img`in the code, e.g. `<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />` in version 1.7.0.2

## Add something before the products

You can define in the backend for every category a `cms_block` to be shown on the category page.

The category page is defined here:

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml
```

as with the product list, if you want to change anything you want to copy this template to your own theme.

You can see at the end of the template, that the cms block is inserted:

```
<?php if($this->isContentMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($this->isMixedMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>

<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can change here a lot, e.g. put the block after the product listing, if you want this.

The CMS-Block must be filled and created in the backend under `CMS > CMS Blocks`. Which block is used for which category is defined at the category: `Catalog > Manage Categories > Click on one Category > Content(?)`